# Handle button action in a list

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to develop an iphone application using sencha framework .I need to show a list of items in a list.Each cell in the list holds a button also.If the user clicks on a button in a particular index, then a popover needs to be displayer near to the button .I am using the following code to do this

```
itemTpl : '<div class="div1"><label class = "tag-name-hdr"> {tagnamehdr} </label> <label class = "tag-name-value" style="width:55px;"> value </label>   <input type="text" class ="tag-name-text" name="lname" />  <label class = "unit-name" > unit </label> <select class = "unit-name_dropdown" > <option>mg/dr</option> <option>gm/dr</option> <option>m/dr</option> </select> <input type="image" id="popupbtn" class="template_popup_button" src="Images/arrow_more_orange.png" > </div>',

        listeners : {
            //itemtap : function(list, index, item, e, popupbtn) {
            itemtap : function(list, index, item, evt) {
                if(evt.getTarget('.template_popup_button')) {

                    alert(item);
                    alert(index);
                    showOverlay(item, evt, index);

                }
            }
        }
```

Now my issue is that the popover is showing for the selected cell.I need to show the popover near to the clicked button.Is there any way to get the clicked button object to show the overlay/popover near to that.Now I am passing clicked item cell object as parameter to "showOverlay",i need to pass clicked button object 
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `evt` variable holds information about the event. You could check if `evt.target` is a button (or the button you want to act upon).

Note that if all you want is a single button per cell, you could use the `onItemDisclosure` config option, that will add a button for you with a handler.